# How to loop through dropdown options, when each option opens new link

Tags: java, selenium

How can I loop through each option in dropdown, while each option opens a new link on computer and after finishing working with the current option, I need to go to the next option of dropdown. Now, to get to the next option I am coming back to the window, where there is a dropdown and I am clicking next option from there. So, is it possible, to get to the next option right after I have finished working with the current one?

When option is selected, the linked document is opened in the parent frame, it means the link is opened in the same page. It has _parent tag, it acts the same like `<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_parent">`

```
<select id="ab" name = "ab"
          onchange = "javascript: var sel = getElementById('ab').selectedIndex;
          var val = getElementById('ab').options[sel].value;
          parent.location='http://ab/football/player_detail.php'+val;">

    <option value='?rez=77777playerNid=1&controls=2:4:5'>Nike.com</option>
    <option value='?rez=464677playerNid=4&controls=2:4:5'>diablo.com</option>
```

Comment: what does "while each option opens a new link on computer" it mean?

Comment: Does it mean opens a new window?

Comment: Okay this can be handled

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

**UPDATED:**

```
            Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ab")));
            for(int i =0; i<select.getOptions().size();i++){
                select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ab")));

                //selecting options
                select.selectByIndex(i);



                /*you can do nour work here depending upon option selected
                 * .
                 * .
                 * .
                 */


                driver.navigate().back();
            }
```

Comment: I tried with your code, but it gave error: **java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: name=null**. In your code, I have inserted following part: `driver.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.switchTo().frame("footballer_detail_frame");
            findFootballer();`

Comment: can you share your URL?

Comment: sorry, but I cannot share link. I tried to resolve the problem myself and googled a little bit, it seems the problem is window handling.

Comment: driver.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle);

Comment: please  print newWindowHandle  before this statement and share the output; also is the new tab opening before this statement.

Comment: I printed it out, there is nothing in newWindowHandle, regarding your 2nd question, programm is stopping at that point and nothing is opening

Comment: you can try one thing put `Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ab")));` as First line in the `for` loop, check my updated answer

Comment: Now, for loop cannot see select.getOptions().size(), because it is defined inside the for loop

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException. It is because of this part `Select select=null;
            for(int i =0; i<select.getOptions().size();i++)` It cannot get options, when select is null

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: name=null

Comment: I am sorry, I formulated my idea incorrectly, I have edited my post, in short, when the option is selected the link is opened on the same page, due to "_parent" tag

Comment: okay, then you don't have to worry about window handles; you just complete your work on new url and then come back to original using `driver.navigate().back();` to start anew; just remember that you'll have to find all the elements once again; just like in this case `select'